# Notifications in Chromium snap

Tags: chromium, snap, notification, 19.10

Since the Chromium package transitioned to snap in Eoan, desktop notifications seem to have stopped working. Is there something that needs to be enabled or installed or some way to get them to work?

Notifications work via libnotify in all other software and worked in Chromium just before the switch.